# pop a specific element off a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have a vector `v` and it has three elements: `{1,2,3}`.

Is there a way to specifically pop `2` from the vector so the resulting vector becomes `{1,3}`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for the element containing the value `2`, not the value at index `2`.

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){
   std::vector<int> a={1,2,3};
   a.erase(std::find(a.begin(),a.end(),2));
}
```

(I used C++0x to avoid some boilerplate, but the actual use of `std::find` and `vector::erase` doesn't require C++0x)

Comment: @kamikaze: Worst case of course `O(n)`, aka it needs to search through the whole vector. If you have a sorted vector, you can try [`lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

Comment: If finding elements by value is a common operation on your vector, you should be using a `std::set` or `std::unsorted_set` instead.

Answer (score 44):

```
//erase the i-th element
myvector.erase (myvector.begin() + i);
```

(Counting the first element in the vector as as `i=0`)

Comment: yeah but what if you want to delete by element not position....so for instance in python you can pop a list pop(x) if that element in the list is x regardless of its position

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: Are you sure you can do that with a python list?

Comment: In Python `pop` deletes an item by index (Todd's answer), and `remove` deletes an item by value (my answer).

Answer (score 10):

Also, remember to use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) if you are removing multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  unsigned int i;
  vector<unsigned int> myvector;

  // set some values (from 1 to 10)
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  // erase the 6th element
  myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+5);

  // erase the first 3 elements:
  myvector.erase (myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+3);

  cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++)
    cout << " " << myvector[i];
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You copied that code from some place. Where is it from? --> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/

Comment: That's a bad answer, Christo. Check what @Todd did with 2 lines only.

Comment: @Karlphillip: Perhaps it would help to read the code a bit more carefully -- this is a complete, compilable program. The erasing is only a couple of lines, about the same amount as @Todd's answer. What this adds is intializing, printing out the result, etc.

Comment: @Jerry Maybe I exaggerated on my comment. But I still don't think that throwing code without an explanation is a good answer, specially when the code was copied from somebody else. This was a copy/paste answer without reference to the author.

Comment: @Karlphillip: Well, I'd certainly agree with that -- just posting a chunk of code with no explanation is rarely very helpful. Failing to attribute the code doesn't (IMO) affect its quality as an answer, but is discourteous if you can avoid it. I've done it a few times with code I'd had lying around for a long time, and lost track of where it came from, but never really intentionally.

Comment: @Jerry I enjoy your blog, by the way. You should post more often. **=)**

Comment: @karlphillip: I was thinking of that last night, but didn't get a chance. I'm glad to hear somebody's getting something out of it -- it's a bit hard to guess whether anybody's even noticed that it exists. I'll see what I can do about posting a bit more often...

Comment: @karlphilip: yeah, I should have put the URL up there, but it's the C++ STL doco, and I figured if he didn't find erase() maybe he needed something a little more full.

Answer (score 1):

From **C++ 20**, we can use `std::erase` for removing **multiple** elements.

(no need for "[erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,2,3,4,5};
      
    std::erase(v, 2);
    
    for(auto e : v) std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    // output: 1 3 4 5
}
```